# Objects are not valid as a React child?

Tags: reactjs

The following function sets the state of my React app, personData being an object:

```
request('https://swapi.co/api/people/?search='+event.target.value, (error,response,body) => {
  this.setState({personData: JSON.parse(body)});
  console.log(this.state)
})
```

Then in the render function:

```
     <td>{this.state.personData}</td>
```

I get the error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'. How can I fix this?

Comment: logging right after setting the state is only going to give you the old state.

Comment: Simply remove `JSON.parse()` so it becomes `this.setState({personData: body});` Also, @Chris is right, you need to use a callback `this.setState({personData: body}, () => console.log(this.state));`

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to render the JSON response, you will have to stringify the response

```
<td>JSON.stringify(this.state.personData, null, 2)</td>
```